# Does '==', '>', or '<' work in Fortran 90?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I recently wrote a fortran90 code after writing lots of C and C++ code.  I wrote some IF and ELSE IF statements in my fortran code, but wrote them using C syntax.  For example,

```
IF (a>b) THEN
BLAH BLAH BLAH
END IF
```

instead of

```
IF (a.gt.b) THEN
BLAH BLAH BLAH
END IF
```

My fortran compiled and it seemed like it was working properly  My question, does this really work in fortran90?

Comment: Yes, these operators are defined in `fortran90` and later, the other operators `.gt.` for example, are required in `fortran77` and earlier

Comment: So, the obvious answer is an emphatic 'YES', both operators are allowed. However, I am very curious why the change was made, whether it was technologically or socially driven, etc. A study like the one conducted here would be cool: https://medium.com/re-form/x-to-close-417936dfc0dc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. According to the Fortran 90 Standard (ISO/IEC 1539:1991):

ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N001-N1100/N692.pdf

> 7.1.1.5  relational operators rel-op:

```
is .EQ. 
or .NE. 
or .LT. 
or .LE. 
or .GT. 
or .GE. 
or == 
or /= 
or < 
or <= 
or > 
or >=
```

Comment: @ja72 I rolled back your change, I'm quoting 7.1.1.5, your edit is not the content of 7.1.1.5.

Answer (score 1):

According to this http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/F90-Basics.pdf (page 23) yes, it does.